# How to click on a dynamic changing link (Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: selenium, junit4

I want to click a link using id property inside span tag , don't know if it helps to click the link.

Here are two different examples of HTML code

1.

```
<span class="handIcon" title="Click Task" id="hand_175931762" campaignid="799214" link="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100006050206969" onclick="updateTask(175931762, this)"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up custom"></i></span>
```

2.

```
<span id="hand_175931760" campaignid="802712" link="https://www.facebook.com/Majumder-Enterprise-154524208363753/"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up custom"></i></span>
```

Where handIcon is the Link Image.

In 1.`id="hand_175931762"` is different from 2.`id="hand_175931760"` HTML code.

They are the links which I wanted to click that changes dynamically , when one link is clicked there is a wait of 30 seconds , after that the next link is active , then again 30 seconds wait , goes on .

I am using this code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'hand')]")).click();,
```

But it throws me Error

```
org.openqa.selenium:ElementNotVisibleException
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of `id` attribute is not a `text()`, so your element couldn't be matched with `"//*[contains(text(),'hand')]"`. This could be applied only if your element looks like `<span>hand_175931762</span>`

Try following instead:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(@id, 'hand_')]")).click();
```

Comment: When I use Selenium IDE , command is Click , then Target is //span[@id='hand_175931753']/i , so I have to check when is link active or which link is active , I think that logic will work , but not sure .

Comment: `XPath` with hardcoded `id` value will not work. What do you mean `check when is link active or which link is active`?

Comment: There are 100 links which are active one by one , when you click on the link it's pop up will remain active 30 seconds and then closes by itself , then the next link is active , till then all the links are deactivated .

Comment: UPDATE: I am not able to make a click on XPath variable (Not able to use .click();) Here is the code I am using   <pre>innerimage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr[56]/td[4]/span[2]/i")).getText();
  System.out.println(innerimage);</pre>

Comment: Your code is not for click, but for getting text of element. Also you shouldn't use this `XPath`! I mean `/form/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/di‌​v/div/div[4]/table[2‌​]/tbody/tr[56]/td[4]‌​/span[2]/i`. It's awful :) Don't ever use `XPath` like this! Try `'//span[@link="https://www.facebook.com/Majumder-Enterprise-154524208363753/"]/i'` instead

Answer (score 0):

Code works , as it does not give any error , but link does not gets clicked , because the ID of the link has changed , because that link with this ID  `<span>hand_175931762</span>` has been clicked .No longer active link.

```
<span>hand_175931762</span>
```

to

```
<span class="handIcon" title="Click Task" id="hand_175931753" campaignid="797945" link="www.SAP.in" onclick="updateTask(175931753, this)"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up custom"></i></span>
```

That

Thanks @Andersson